# Evaluating the expected value of $\log(g(x))$.

Tags: probability, statistics, summation

I am trying to evaluate the expected value of $\log(x+r)$ with respect to a negative binomial distribution.  In other words, I am searching for a closed form or approximation to the quantity
\begin{equation}
\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}\log{\left(x+r\right)}\frac{\Gamma(x+r)}{x!\Gamma(r)}{(1-p)^r}{p^x}
\end{equation}
where $p\in(0,1)$.  So far, I have tried to use the result [in this post from 2012](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/38296/expected-value-of-a-natural-logarithm), however this approximation does not seem that accurate when I compare it to the numerical computation of this quantity(truncating the sum at some large value), particularly for smaller values of $p$.  Any help would be appreciated, thanks for your time.

Comment: To help with the approximation: do you want to approximate it for fixed (constant) $r\geq 1$ while $p\to 0$, or for fixed $p>0$ while $r\to \infty$? (Is asymptotics are good enough, asymptotics w.r.t. which quantitiy?)

Comment: @Clement C.: Thanks for the comment.  Ideally, I would like the approximation to be good for fixed $r\ge 1$, especially near the boundaries of $p$.  Does that answer your question?

Comment: I think so. I'd say the case $r\to\infty$ would have been simpler, as then the approximation from the post you link seems valid.

Comment: @Clement C.: Indeed.  When I numerically evaluated that approximation, it was poor for lower values of $r$ and $p$.  This is part of a problem which is deriving a prior for $r$, so ideally it should work well for all $r\ge 1$